# Node.js - Google Cloud Speech API - Event listener problem

Tags: node.js, electron, speech-to-text

I'm using Google Cloud Speech API for [streaming input](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize#speech-streaming-mic-recognize-nodejs).
I need the ability to handle the event that's fired as soon as audio is being detected. I think the appropriate one is [`readable`](https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook#consuming-a-readable-stream).

Except, I couldn't get it to work yet:

- If I attach this event to Speech API's `streamingRecognize()` - it'd behave the same as the `data` listener, except without any parameters.
- If, on the other hand, I attach this event listener to [node-record-lpcm16](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-record-lpcm16#usage)'s `start()` - the event works as expected, but the `pipe()` method seems to fail executing, as Speech API's `data` event is never fired.

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to [this webpage](https://devhints.io/nodejs-stream). It's impossible.
It seems that the first event that's fired is `data`.